# When soap is installed for php, should I include nusoap library?

Tags: php, soap

In output of phpinfo() I see that soap extension is installed. I have a documentation for a webservice that in it's example it includes nusoap library.

Is nusoap library needed when soap extension is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically its not needed, no.

However, the SOAP facilities built in to PHP are not fun to work with, particularly if the services you're consuming are moderately complex (my adventure into hell was with EBay).

Were I you, I would still use NuSoap or Zend_Soap. Doubly so given that the PHP examples/documentation use NuSoap already. You'll save yourself a lot of headache just sticking with that.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not required http://www.php.net/manual/en/soap.requirements.php